# Show that $\forall p\in\mathbb{N}$: $ y_t\in\overline{\text{co}}\bigcup_{n\geq p}{f_n(E\smallsetminus N)} $

Tags: analysis

Let $(E,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be finite measure space, and $\{f_n\}\subset L_{\mathbb{R}}^{1}$.

Let $\{s_n\}$ be a sequence of function such that :
$$
s_n :=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}{f_n}
$$
Suppose that : $\exists N\in \mathcal{A}$, $\mu(N)=0$ such that:
$$
\forall t\in E\smallsetminus N~,~\exists y_t\in\mathbb{R}~~:~s_n(t) \to y_t
$$
Show that $\forall p\in\mathbb{N}$:
$$
y_t\in\overline{\text{co}}\bigcup_{n\geq p}{f_n(E\smallsetminus N)}
$$
with :
$$
\overline{\text{co}}(A)=\overline{\{y~:~y=\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\lambda_ix_i~,~\text{with}~\lambda_i\in[0,1]~, ~\text{such that}~\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\lambda_i}=1,~\text{and }x_i\in A,~n\in\mathbb{N} }\}}
$$
such that $A\subset \mathbb{R}$.

An idea please.

Comment: Hint: For a set $A$ of real numbers $\overline {co} (A)$ is nothing but the interval $[m,M]$ where $m=\inf A$ and $M=\sup A$.

Comment: But if we change $ \mathbb {R} $ to Banach space $X$. what will happen?

Comment: in other words : $\{f_n\}\subset L_{X}^{1}$ (Bochner integrable)